# Data encryption for Api using Python

Tags: python, api, post, encryption, fernet

I need to encrypt a certain output and send it to an api using post req

```
message = {'Id':1,'Desktop':dtop[0],'Mobile':mob[0]}
message1=json.dumps(message)
print(message1)

key = Fernet.generate_key()
print('key',key)
fernet = Fernet(key)

encrypted = fernet.encrypt(message1.encode())
print('Encrypted Success')
payload = {'Input=encrypted'}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
r = requests.post('https:xyz url',headers=headers ,data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if you send over https it is encrypted already? also your code looks fine, what is the problem

Comment: the payload={'input=encrypted'} is not working

Comment: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: and if i didnt use the json.dump function the encode() function didnt work.